# multiple functions in the document.ready function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.flip1').click(function () {
        $('.panel1').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $('.flip2').click(function () {
        $('.panel2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $('.flip3').click(function () {
        $('.panel3').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $('.flip4').click(function () {
        $('.panel4').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I want to make a loop with .flip as the variable (flipVar) and .panel as (panelVar)

Comment: let me add that the number of elements are unknown and the range isn't necessarily from flip1-flip4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you want to run the selector in a loop, I wouldn't do it like that because you're doing multiple DOM selections. You can get it done with one DOM selection:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div[class^=flip]').each(function ( idx ) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('.panel' + (idx + 1)).slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

This will work assuming that the `flip` elements occur on the page in their numerical order.

This uses [the attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get all `<div>` elements that have a class name starting with `"flip"`. Change the tag name if it is different, or remove it if they don't all have the same tag.

It uses the `index` that `.each()` makes available to you in order to toggle the correct `.panel`.

Comment: not only is this the best way, but depending on the HTML, this could be simplified by doing something like `$(this).find('div[class^=panel]').slideToggle('slow')` and you wouldn't even need the index :)

Comment: @Jason: +1 Good point. Very likely that some manner of traversal could be used inside the handler instead of DOM selection.

Answer (score 4):

Well if it were my page I'd make sure that those elements all shared a class so that I wouldn't *need* to loop. However, you could do this:

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) $('.flip' + i).click((function(i) {
   return function() { $('.panel' + i).slideToggle('slow'); };
 })(i));
```

The loop variable has to be trapped in a closure so that each "click" handler references the proper value. Again, I really wouldn't do it this way. I'd make the "flip" elements share a class, and then keep that index (the implicit reference to a corresponding "panel") in a separate class element or in a "data-" attribute. Then the handler could find the panel using that value.

*edit* — as a hack, you could leverage the fact that the class names of the related elements are both of the form "somethingNN", where "NN" is the numeric part. You could strip off the number and then append it to "panel":

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) $('.flip' + i).click(function() {
  var panelClass = this.className.replace(/.*\bflip(\d+).*/, "panel$1");
  $(panelClass).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: I'll have to look up making classes in javascript.  Would making a class work for an unknown number of elements?  The menu and submenu is created from a database and could be any size depending on what the user inputs.

Comment: No, the class would be on the elements, just as "flip1" is in the element class already.

Comment: good point, giving all elements single class (flip) will certainly save a lot of processing and traversal if you're having a lot of elements to be toggled on page... or, if altogether neccessary, try giving those elements an ID instead of class - it's much faster to look for an ID than a class of an element for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
       (function(i) {
          $('.flip'+i).click(function () {
             $('.panel'+i).slideToggle("slow");
          });
       })(i);
    }

});
```

Comment: So I used this as a quick "bandage" to my problem until I figure out javascript classes. It worked out.  I had a count keep track of my elements and replaced 4 with that count. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
         $('.flip'+i).click(function () {
             $('.panel'+i).slideToggle("slow");
         });
    }
});
```

PS:- don't use this it will not work as pointed out by @patrick

Comment: This won't work because the value of `i` references inside the `click` handler will always reflect the most recent update. Likely `5` in this case.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing @patrick. I've not tested this. I missed `.click` totally. :( silly me!

Comment: You were close though. Just needed a closure to retain the value of `i` for `$('.panel'+i)`.

Comment: @patrick please edit the answer to let me know how to do this. I'm weak on closures. Maybe it will be like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147051/4147085#4147085 answer by @fcalderan